# Dimension name clash between two included libraries

Tags: android, android-resources, android-library

I have an app that includes two libraries, both of which define a dimension with the same name (say `text_size`). At runtime I can see the style from one library is using the dimensions from the other.

Beyond namespacing all the dimension in each library (e.g. `lib1_text_size`) is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find any solution to this. I ended up namespacing every single resource in my library. Luckily it was my library and that was possible.